# Kafka: move partition from invalid broker

Tags: java, apache-kafka, distributed-computing

I have an invalid broker, which doesn't really exists. I started a server with invalid id by mistake, for a moment.

But one of the topics was assigned to this broker before:

```
Topic:raw-logs  PartitionCount:3    ReplicationFactor:1 Configs:
    Topic: raw-logs Partition: 0    Leader: -1      Replicas: 100   Isr:
    Topic: raw-logs Partition: 1    Leader: none    Replicas: 2     Isr:
    Topic: raw-logs Partition: 2    Leader: none    Replicas: 3     Isr:
```

I've already tried to reassign partitions with

```
{"topic":"raw-logs","partition":0,"replicas":[1]}
```

But it doesn't change anything. I guess Kafka waits until original Broker 100 will go up to copy data from it to Broker 1. Am I right?

But what if I don't don't want it? i'm ok to lose all data from this broker. Can I force Kafka to select new leader and rebalance topic? Manually, from command line

Answer (score 0):

just guessing, but have you tried to use the bin/kafka-preferred-replica-election.sh --zookeeper zk_host:port/chroot  method.

Comment: yeah, I've tried too, nothing changed :( as a result i've recreated whole cluster from the ground. it was test env, so not a big problem, but still a question what to do if i'll get same situation in prod